# Smart Pointers and Exception

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

A practice question on C++ primer:

> one easy way to make sure resources are freed is to use smart pointers.

Imagine we're using a network library that is used by both C and C++. Programs that use this library might contain code such as:

```
struct connection
{
    string ip;
    int port;
    connection(string i, int p) :ip(i), port(p) {};
};  // represents what we are connecting to

struct destination
{
    string ip;
    int port;
    destination(string i, int p) :ip(i), port(p) {};
};  // information needed to use the connection

void disconnect(connection c)
{
    cout << "Scoket(" << c.port << "," << c.port << ") disconnect" << endl;
}  //close the given connection

connection connect(destination* pDest)
{
    shared_ptr<connection> pConn(new connection(pDest->ip, pDest->port), disconnect );
    cout << "Scoket(" << pConn->ip << "," << pConn->port << ") connect" << endl;
    return *pConn;
}  // open the connection


void f(destination& d)
{
    connection c = connect(&d);
}
```

compile error:

```
error C2661: 'std::shared_ptr<connection>::shared_ptr': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments.
```

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr), there is indeed an overload that takes two arguments, but it doesn't work the way you want. You're looking at overload (4).

> ```
> template< class Y, class Deleter >
> shared_ptr( Y* ptr, Deleter d );
> ```
>
> Uses the specified deleter `d` as the deleter. **The expression `d(ptr)` must be well formed,** have well-defined behavior and not throw any exceptions. The construction of `d` and of the stored deleter copied from it must not throw exceptions.

(emphasis mine)

Note that the deleter must be a callable object which accepts an argument of type `Y*`, i.e. a pointer to the data within the `std::shared_ptr`. So your `disconnect` function, if you intend to use it as a deleter for a `std::shared_ptr`, should have signature

```
void disconnect(connection* c)
```

with a pointer argument.

Also note that your shared pointer, as it's written, is already very likely to exhibit undefined behavior.

> ```
> connection connect(destination* pDest)
> {
>     shared_ptr<connection> pConn(new connection(pDest->ip, pDest->port), disconnect );
>     cout << "Scoket(" << pConn->ip << "," << pConn->port << ") connect" << endl;
>     return *pConn;
> }
> ```

Let's break down what you've done here. First, you create a shared pointer to a new connection object. That connection object is owned and managed by the `std::shared_ptr`. When there are no more `std::shared_ptr` objects pointing to that memory, it will be deallocated, and your deleter will run. Then you return (a copy of) the underlying connection. The `std::shared_ptr` is a local variable and is freed as a matter of course, and that was the only shared pointer to the `connection*` you allocated. Hence, `disconnect` shall be called. As soon as `connect` returns, it returns a copy of a connection which has already been closed. If someone tries to use the `connection` object, it will fail, or worse, exhibit undefined behavior.

If you're going to use smart pointers, you have to commit to it. Your `connect` function must return a `std::shared_ptr<connection>`, which the caller then manages. Constructing a shared pointer does no good if all you return is a raw pointer.

Comment: How should I modify this program to use smart pointers? Thank you so much!

Comment: In C++, connect() should return shared_ptr<connection> so its caller can manage the lifetime.  Of course, C wouldn't like that, so you would have to wrap the C++ object that does the memory management behind a C-friendly interface.

Answer (score 0):

The deleter you give to your `std::shared_ptr` needs to accept a pointer of the same type that the `shared_ptr` manages.  So for a `std::shared_ptr<connection>`, the deleter needs to accept a `connection*`, but that's not what `disconnect` accepts.  The signatures don't match, and the program fails to compile.

Of note, you have several other issues in your example.  `disconnect` does not `delete` the object passed to it, so the object managed by `pConn` will leak.  Additionally, `connect` returns a copy of the object pointed to by `pConn`, so there's no reason to use a `std::shared_ptr` or dynamic allocation at all.